# Did Karna think that it was adharma to not appoint Duryodhana as king of Hastinapura?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, karna, duryodhana

In Star Plus Mahabharata (e.g., [S11 E7](https://www.hotstar.com/tv/mahabharat/s-28/duryodhan-provokes-dhritarashtra/1000011885)), it is shown again and again that Karna believed that it was adharma to not appoint Duryodhana as King/Yuvaraja (crown prince) of Hastinapura.

Did Karna really believe so according to the original Mahabharata text? If yes, what reasons did he offer?

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of *[Why was Yudishthir considered to be the next King after Dhritrashtra and not Duryodhana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7851)* which is a general question about Duryodhana and his rights whereas this is more about what Karna believed and why.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is more concerned about Karna. THe other question is about Duryodhana.

Comment: It is normal for any person to feel if their best friend has participated in some competition and lost. Karna also wanted Duryodhana to be the emperor. TV serials are bad sources to learn about Mahabharata and Ramayana. Writers take artistic license and write as their wish to show their personal favorite characters in lime light.

Comment: *It is normal for any person to feel if their best friend has participated in some competition and lost. Karna also wanted Duryodhana to be the emperor* Does it mean Karna's belief was wrong?

Comment: I haven't watched episode you linked but Karna believed Duryodhana should be the king. He also fought in behalf of Duryodhana and gave away the kingdoms he won to Duryodhana.