# Why Vrishketu not ascended the throne of Hastinapur

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, karna, kings

Karna was elder brother of Pandavas. As per the ancient Indian monarchial system, eldest son has a right over throne of his father. Vrishketu was the only son of Karna survived after Mahabharat war and real owner of throne. So why he didn't get the throne?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Dhritarashtra, why was Yudhishthira and not Duryodhana considered the next in line to be the king?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/after-dhritarashtra-why-was-yudhishthira-and-not-duryodhana-considered-the-next)

Comment: @YDS I am not asking about DURYODHAN.

Comment: your main point is "As per the ancient Indian monarchial system, eldest son has a right over throne of his father" which is answered in this post..

Comment: @YDS - But there is no way Karna was ineligible when you have Sri Krishna offering him the kingdom

Comment: but Karna died...now among Vrishketu and Yudhisthira, i think Yudhisthira would be more eligible as he had been Samrat already...

Comment: @YDS - As far as I can tell there was no Vrishketu. Mentioned the same in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First by defintion, Karna was a *Kanina* and could be made king

[Manusmriti 9.172](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201551.html) says

> pitṛveśmani kanyā tu yaṃ putraṃ janayed rahaḥ |
>   taṃ kānīnaṃ vadennāmnā voḍhuḥ kanyāsamudbhavam || 172 ||
>
> If a maiden secretly bears a son in her father’s house, that son, born of a maiden, should be declared as ‘maiden-born’ by name, and to belong to the man who marries her.—(172)

Lord Krishna, in Udyoga Parva, [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05140.htm) the following to Karna

> It is said by those conversant with the scriptures that the two kinds of sons called Kanina and Sahoda that are born of a maiden, have him for their father who weddeth the maid. Thou, O Karna, hast been born in this way. Thou art, therefore, morally the son of Pandu. Come, be a king, according to the injunction of the scriptures

So there is no doubt that Karna and his descendants were eligible.

Now why wasn't Vrishaketu made the King ? That is because there was **no such person** in Mahabharata.

The only reference of Vrishaketu was found [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06017.htm) in KMG Mahabharata

> That large force of the Easterners looking like the fleecy clouds of autumn 3 was (besides) protected by the chief of the Angas (Karna's son Vrishaketu) and Kripa endued with great energy.

But this seems to translation error. The [sanskrit](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06017.htm) verse (see number 28) only says "chief of Angas" - who was Vrishasena (son of Karna), who died in the war

> tad aṅgapatinā guptaṃ kṛpeṇa ca mahātmanā
>        śāradābhracaya prakhyaṃ prācyānām abhavad balam